# SQL show USA as United States of America

Tags: sql

```
SELECT Country From Employees
```

result:

[image]

I want to show United States of America instead of USA

Comment: Just `USA`, or do you want to show `UK` as `United Kingdom` as well?

Comment: I'm using northwind

Comment: also Uk as United Kingdom

Comment: then use a case statement

Comment: Or use a translation table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.

```
SELECT 
CASE Country
WHEN 'US' THEN 'United States of America'
WHEN 'UK' THEN 'United Kingdom'
-- ...any other translation you would like to add here
ELSE Country
END AS DisplayCountry
From Employees
```

Comment: only remove = in "WHEN = 'UK' THEN 'United Kingdom' "

Answer (score 8):

The country names are not in the database, so you must get them from somewhere.

The natural thing would be to introduce a country table, e.g.

```
country   name
USA       United States of America
UK        United Kingdom
...
```

and join this.

Another option is to have all names in your query as shown in the other answers.

Answer (score 1):

Use `CASE WHEN ... THEN ...`

```
SELECT Country CASE WHEN 'USA' THEN ' United States of America'
                    WHEN 'UK'  THEN ' United Kingdom '
                    ELSE Country
                    END
FROM Employees
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT CASE WHEN [COUNTRY] = 'USA' THEN 'United States Of America' 
WHEN [COUNTRY] = 'UK'THEN 'UNITED KINGDOM' ELSE [COUNTRY] END AS [COUNTRY_FULL]
FROM [Employees]
```

Thats an example of a case statement that you could use:

http://www.1keydata.com/sql/sql-case.html

Comment: A side note: The brackets around column and table names are non-standard and only allowed in few DBMS.

Answer (score 0):

Introduce another table country

```
Code      Full_name
___________________________________
 USA       United States of America
 UK        United Kingdom
 etc....
```

Then join **Employee** table with **country**

```
SELECT Full_Name FROM Employee e
LEFT JOIN Country c ON e.country = c.Code
```